# Non-Noetherian local ring $(R,m)$'s completion $\hat{R}$ flat? Non finitely generated module $M$, then $\hat{R}\otimes_RM\to \hat{M}$ not isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring not necessarily Noetherian with maximal ideal $m$.

Let $\hat{R}$ completion of $(R,m)$ by $\varprojlim_s\frac{R}{m^s}$. Simultaneously, consider a non finitely generated module $M$, then $\hat{R}\otimes_RM\to \hat{M}$ where $\hat{M}=\varprojlim_s\frac{M}{m^sM}$.(This map is induced from $\hat{R}\to\frac{R}{m^s}$ map by tensoring $M$ to induce inverse system map.)

$\textbf{Q1:}$ Is $\hat{R}$ still flat as I have dropped Noetherian condition? If not, what is counter example?

$\textbf{Q2:}$ Is $\hat{R}\otimes_R M\to\hat{M}$ still isomorphism as I dropped finite generation condition? If not, what is counter example?

$\textbf{Q3:}$ Can $Q1$ and $Q2$ scenario be independent of each other? If yes, what is the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About **Q1**:

Take for example $C= K[Y, X_0, \ldots, X_n, \ldots]/(YX_0, X_0-YX_1, \ldots, X_n - YX_{n+1}, \ldots)$ and let $R=C[T]$. Then the $T$-adic completion $\hat{R}$ is isomorphic to $C[\![T]\!]$, but this is not flat over $R$. Namely, $R \rightarrow R, x \mapsto (Y-T)x$ is injective, but $\hat{R} \rightarrow \hat{R}, x \mapsto (Y-T)x$ is not injective.

About **Q2**:

Take for example $R= \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, $M= \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[X]$. Then $\hat{R} \otimes_R M \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[X] \cong \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\hat{M} = \{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} p^if_i \mid f_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[X] \} \cong \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_p$. Those are not isomorphic.

About **Q3**:

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you are asking for, but the above answers should be "independent" enough from each other.